# Map to <bean> to knockout .js

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, knockout.js

I have the following bean in a jsp file:

```
<bean:write name="somename" property="someproperty" />
```

I need to be able to use this data in knockout.js but I have no idea how to map a bean to json for use in knockout. 
Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to realize, **where** and **when** each code is executed - JSP on the server when the page is requested and rendered (i.e. **before** the response is sent to the browser) and Javascript in the browser, **after** the browser receives the **already generated** response.

So if you want to use your property to "statically" initialize your KO model, you can do it in your JSP page. But if you want to read the property dynamically, when user already interacts with your KO application, you have to create a servlet to be called via AJAX as described e.g. in http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html